# Can not select item from dropdown Robotframework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I tried to locate the drop down to select value but get exception

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view
```

I used below statement

```
Select From List by Value    xpath=//select[@id="appgroups"]    2
```

Please see my image for your reference. Please help me [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hFo8.png)

Comment: try to wait before selecting option value

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @AnkurSingh: What is the wait command you refer to

Answer (score 0):

Please check my html code as below (I can't attached in my question because the code is too long, and not allow)

```
<div id="dlg_crud" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="dlg_crud_title"></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="frm_crud" class="form-horizontal form-margin">
            <input type="hidden" id="task" value="">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label align-left">Mã ứng dụng:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <input class="crud form-control input-xs" type="text" id="appcode" name="appcode" maxlength="30"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label align-left">Nhóm ứng dụng:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <select id="appgroups" name="appgroups" class="crud form-control input-sm" >
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label align-left">SIBS:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <select id="sibstypes" name="sibstypes" class="crud form-control input-sm" >
                                                    <option value="1"><%=Constants.APP_SIBS%></option>
                                                    <option value="2"><%=Constants.APP_NONSIBS%></option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label align-left">Mô tả:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <input class="crud form-control input-xs" type="text" id="appdesc" name="appdesc" maxlength="500"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label align-left">Ứng dụng gom gộp:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <select id="appagg" name="appagg" class="crud form-control input-xs">
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label align-left">Đường dẫn ứng dụng:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <input class="crud form-control input-xs" type="text" id="weblink" name="weblink" maxlength="200"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label align-left">Mã phần mềm:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <input class="crud form-control input-xs" type="text" id="swcode" name="swcode" maxlength="30"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label align-left">Tên ứng dụng:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <input class="crud form-control input-xs" type="text" id="appname" name="appname" maxlength="200"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label align-left">Loại ứng dụng:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <select id="apptypes" name="apptypes" class="crud form-control input-sm" >
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label align-left">Trạng thái:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <select id="statuses" name="statuses" class="crud form-control input-sm" >
                                                    <option value="1"><%=Constants.APP_ACTIVE%></option>
                                                    <option value="0"><%=Constants.APP_INACTIVE%></option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label align-left">Nhóm xử lý:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <select id="actids" name="actids" multiple="multiple" class="crud form-control input-xs">
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label align-left"></label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <div class="ckbox ckbox-primary cb-form">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="multiusr" id="multiusr" />
                                                    <label for="multiusr" class="text-danger" style="padding-top: 10px;">Sử dụng nhiều user/nhóm quyền</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label align-left">Mật khẩu mặc định:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <input class="crud form-control input-xs" type="text" id="defpass" name="defpass" maxlength="100"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>  
                </div>
              </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">                
                <% if (Utils.checkSubMenu(subfunclist, "create") || Utils.checkSubMenu(subfunclist, "update")) { %>
                <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"></button>
                <% } %>
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Đóng</button>                 
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code to select dropdown list

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

Select drp = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("appgroups")));
drp.selectByVisibleText("your value here");
```

Comment: How can I use your code in Ride editor/Robotframework ?

Comment: It looks like you've posted java. Robotframework is based on python.